# How to get remote data after sending them from python

Tags: python, http-post, urllib2, http-get

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import urllib2
import os
from bottle import GET, POST, REQUEST, RUN, bottle

application = app = bottle()

def get_result(exam, year, board, roll):
    base_url = "http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/regular" #switch to archive.educationboard.gov.bd if this fails

    index_response = urllib2.urlopen(base_url + "/index.php")
    session_var = index_response.info().headers[3].split()[1][0:36] #getting PHPSESSID session cookie
    post_data = "sr=3&et=0&exam=%s&year=%s&board=%s&roll=%s&button2=Submit" % (exam, year, board, roll)

    result_request = urllib2.Request(base_url + "/result.php", headers = {'Cookie': session_var})
    result_response = urllib2.urlopen(result_request, post_data)
    return result_response.read()

@app.route('/')
def index_page():
    # just the info entry page, don't validate HTML, please!
    return '''<html><head><meta property="og:image" content="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/128/Network-Upload-icon.png"/><title>Board Result Grabber</title><meta name="description" content="Get your board result before anyone else does! (Probably, even before they get published)"></head>
        <body style="padding: 2em; font-family: Ubuntu, 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;">
        <h2>Board Result Fetcher</h2>
        <form action="/check" method="post" >
        Exam: <select name="exam">
                            <option value="hsc">HSC/Alim/Equivalent</option>
                            <option value="jsc">JSC/JDC</option>
                            <option value="ssc">SSC/Dakhil</option>
                            <option value="ssc_voc">SSC(Vocational)</option>
                            <option value="hsc">HSC/Alim</option>
                            <option value="hsc_voc">HSC(Vocational)</option>
                            <option value="hsc_hbm">HSC(BM)</option>
                            <option value="hsc_dic">Diploma in Commerce</option>
                            <option value="hsc_dibs">Diploma in Business Studies</option>
                          </select><br />
        Year: <select id="year" name="year">
                            <option selected="" value="2014">2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option>
                          </select><br />
        Roll: <input name="roll" type="text" maxlength="6"/><br />
        Board: <select id="board" name="board">
                          <option selected="" value="">Select One</option>
                          <option value="barisal">Barisal</option>
                          <option value="chittagong">Chittagong</option>
                          <option value="comilla">Comilla</option>
                          <option value="dhaka">Dhaka</option>
                          <option value="dinajpur">Dinajpur</option>
                          <option value="jessore">Jessore</option>
                          <option value="rajshahi">Rajshahi</option>
                          <option value="sylhet">Sylhet</option>
                          <option value="madrasah">Madrasah</option>
                          <option value="tec">Technical</option>
                          <option value="dibs">DIBS(Dhaka)</option>
                          </select><br /><br />
        <input value="Check result" type="submit" />
        </form></body></html>'''

@app.route('/check', method="POST")
def result():
    roll = request.forms.get("roll")
    board = request.forms.get("board")
    exam = request.forms.get("exam")
    year = request.forms.get("year")
    result = get_result(exam, year, board, roll)
    if result == "Error: QDTL65656565":
        return '''<div style="margin: 1em 4em; padding: 1em; border: 1px solid #dd4814;"><h2>Result Database Tables not found</h2><p>The board site is having issues with their database, probably they have not yet uploaded and propagated the database tables for this years examinees, please keep patience and try a few minutes later.</p></div>'''
    else: return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(app, host='localhost', port=80)
```

But I am getting error from my server on line 5:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./result.py", line 5, in
>   
>       from bottle import GET, POST, REQUEST, RUN, bottle ImportError: No module named bottle

Comment: I don't understand how your title has anything to do with the question. The error indicates this is an import problem.

Comment: @Huu Nguyen Not working here:
from bottle import bottle, GET, POST, REQUEST, RUN > I am trying this
But it says no module named bottle.

Comment: I would install bottle (`pip install bottle`)

Comment: @ShahriarShojib I see you are trying and probably gave Bangladesh's result site a shock. But I really dont think it still works. Is There any new way of doing it?? (I m interested...)

Comment: they now have captcha, this script was not written by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the commenter, first make sure you've installed bottle with `pip install bottle`.

Then, instead of:

```
from bottle import GET, POST, REQUEST, RUN, bottle
application = app = bottle()
```

Use:

```
from bottle import get, post, request, run, Bottle
application = app = Bottle()
```

Tested on the latest `pip`-able version of bottle.